# Running Matlab in Emacs Org-mode Win10

Tags: matlab, org-mode

I am looking for some direction to run Matlab in org-mode on a Win10  machine.
Matlab is installed and fully pathed within windows so it loads without issues.
Matlab is added in the org-babel languages list which loads without error.
These two lines to identify explicitely where matlab is and define header arguments which load without error.

```
(setq matlab-shell-command "c:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2018b/bin/matlab.exe")
(setq org-babel-default-header-args:matlab '((:results . "output") (:session . "*MATLAB*")))
```

When I attempt to run a something simple such as

```
#+begin_src matlab :results output
a=4
b=5
c=a*b
ans=c
#+end_src
```

I receive an error "no such file or directory, matlab".

What is the correct way to identify the location and execution of matlab to process the org-mode block?

(Note: I have extensively googled it but have not found any usable instruction from Win10 users who seem to be few in number.)

Comment: org babel for matlab uses ob-octave.el. In there, it seems that the executable is defined in org-babel-matlab-shell-command. I don't have Windows so cannot verify that changing this would work but have a look.

Comment: I'm suspicious of the directory with a space in its name, either explore how its escaped or see if you can invoke a matlab from (say C:\Progra~1\matlab\ or C:\users\...)